# How to give dynamic color to Column-Chart

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvas, google-visualization

I have a `Column google-chart`  which is displaying on `UI` perfectly, What i am trying to do is to give them each column dynamic color combination

**Snippet**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'amount'],
    ['2012', 900, ],
    ['2013', 1000, ],
    ['2014', 1170, ],
    ['2015', 1250, ],
    ['2016', 1530, ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population (in millions)',
    legend: 'Years', //i want to show legents as year it is showing amount only

  };

  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

In my above snippet it is running fine but i want to make several changes

- I want to put dynamic color so that each column have different color
- after each column have different color i want to show legends as `Years`
- like 2012 2013 while come as legend

I really don't know how to do that,not even getting ideas 
please anyone out here help me.

**Note** :- If there is another opensource chart library i can use with JSON data please let me know, i have tried d3.js but that too did't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add colors: ['skyBlue'] to the options

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Years'],
    
    ['2012', 900 ],
    ['2013', 1000],
    ['2014', 1170],
    ['2015', 1250],
    ['2016', 1530]
  ]);
  
  var options = {
        title: "'Population (in millions)'",
        colors: ['skyBlue']
      };

 

  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

If you need every column of a different color you can do this:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Years', { role: 'style' }],
    
    ['2012', 900,'gold' ],
    ['2013', 1000,'skyBlue'],
    ['2014', 1170,'pink'],
    ['2015', 1250,'lightgreen'],
    ['2016', 1530,'#bac']
  ]);
  
  var options = {
        title: "'Population (in millions)'",
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };

 

  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Yet an other option, this time with a legend:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  // Define the chart to be drawn.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Years', '2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
    ['Years',900, 1000, 1170, 1250, 1530]]);
  
  var options = {
        title: "'Population (in millions)'",
        colors: ['gold', 'skyBlue', 'pink','lightgreen','#bac']
      };

 

  // Instantiate and draw the chart.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('container'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: this one i have already tried here i am using static data so it is ok to give color  statically because here i have only 5 years but as in my data base there are 20-25 years ,so it will not be cool to give it statically

Comment: same buddy,it is taking only one color i.e `skyblue`

Comment: 3rd one that i can prefer but years are not showing on the bottom?

Comment: In this case you may want to create your own SVG code. It's not that hard.